# Process.Start not returning all data

Tags: c#, asynchronous, process

I try to connect to OpenVPN using a C# GUI. My code is as follows:

```
var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "openvpn",
        Arguments = "--config config.ovpn",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};

proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, args) =>
{
    debug.WriteLine(args.Data);
};

proc.ErrorDataReceived += (s, args) =>
{
    debug.WriteLine("ERROR: " + args.Data);
};

proc.Start();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

I get the following output into my debug window:

```
Tue Apr 26 19:04:58 2016 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on Mar 10 2016
Tue Apr 26 19:04:58 2016 Windows version 6.1 (Windows 7)
Tue Apr 26 19:04:58 2016 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1s  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.09
```

This means, it should be working fine. Now the problem is, that I don't get the `Enter Auth Username:` line (which should be there), so I can't parse the output and pass my credentials (if I run the same command on CMD, it works).

I tried the following while experimenting for a while (so it automatically sends a new line to the `InputStream` once the output contains `library versions:`):

```
[...]
proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, args) =>
{
    debug.WriteLine(args.Data);
    if(args.Data != null) if(args.Data.Contains("library versions:")) proc.Write("\r\n");
};
[...]
```

Now my output is the following:

```
Tue Apr 26 19:10:11 2016 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on Mar 10 2016
Tue Apr 26 19:10:11 2016 Windows version 6.1 (Windows 7)
Tue Apr 26 19:10:11 2016 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1s  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.09
ERROR: Enter Auth Username:
Tue Apr 26 19:10:11 2016 ERROR: Auth username is empty
Tue Apr 26 19:10:11 2016 Exiting due to fatal error
ERROR:
```

So he writes the line I want to get to the error stream after I gave him a newline. Why does he behave so strange? And, more important, what can I do to get this line without having to write a new line?

Comment: Okay, so I fixed it by doing `auth-user-pass <passwordfile>` instead of `auth-user-pass` in my `config.ovpn`. But I would really love to know why the hell the openvpn process behaves so strange. Also, when parsing the output and writing to the input stream, I could add encryption to the password database easily. Using a password file, I can't.